# How to use MudSkeleton on Mudtable in Blazor

Tags: blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

Here I am trying to show MudSkeleton before the data loads in the table.
I tried by setting default Loading property to true, but it shows loading animation along with skeleton. I tried below code
if I set Loading to false no skeleton is showing. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
<MudTable Elevation="0" MultiSelection="true" Hover="true" @bind-SelectedItems="_selectedItems"
ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<PagedProductResponse>>>(ServerReloadAsync))" @ref="_table"
T="PagedProductResponse" @bind-CurrentPage="@PageNumber" @bind-RowsPerPage="@PageSize" Loading="true">
<ToolBarContent>
    <MudGrid>
        <TablePager UseUrlQueryPaging="true" PageSizeOptions="@_pageSizeOption" />
    </MudGrid>
</ToolBarContent>
<HeaderContent>
    <MudTh Class="w-30">
        <MudTableSortLabel T="PagedProductResponse" SortBy="c => c.ID" SortLabel="productID">"ID"
        </MudTableSortLabel>
    </MudTh>
    <MudTh Class="w-100">
        <MudTableSortLabel T="PagedProductResponse" SortBy="c => c.Name" SortLabel="productName">"Name"
        </MudTableSortLabel>
    </MudTh>
    <MudTh Class="w-100">
        <MudTableSortLabel T="PagedProductResponse" SortBy="c => c.BasePrice" SortLabel="productPriceField">Unit
            price</MudTableSortLabel>
    </MudTh>

</HeaderContent>
<LoadingContent>
    <MudGrid Class="">
        <MudItem xs="12">
            <MudSkeleton Width="100%" Height="70px" Animation="Animation.Wave" />
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12">
            <MudSkeleton Width="100%" Height="70px" Animation="Animation.Wave" />
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12">
            <MudSkeleton Width="100%" Height="70px" Animation="Animation.Wave" />
        </MudItem>

    </MudGrid>
</LoadingContent>
<RowTemplate>
    <MudTd DataLabel="ID" Class="w-30">
        <MudHighlighter Text="@context.ID" HighlightedText="@_searchString" />
    </MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="productName" Class="w-100">
        @context.Name
    </MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Unit price" Class="w-100">
        @context.BasePrice
    </MudTd>
</RowTemplate>
<PagerContent>
    <TablePager UseUrlQueryPaging="true" PageSizeOptions="@_pageSizeOption" />
</PagerContent>
```

Comment: `LoadingContent` description from [docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/table#properties:~:text=Defines%20the%20table%20body%20content%20the%20table%20has%20no%20rows%20and%20is%20loading) _"Defines the table body content the table has no rows and is loading"_ . So no, you can't show LoadingContent but not the progress indicator.